# How can I get a div content in php

Tags: php

I have a div in php(string) and I want to get the content.

for example:

```
<div id="product_list" style="width:100%; float:none;">
      <div>
       bla bla bla
      </div>
      bla bla          
</div>
```

and I want

```
<div>
     bla bla bla
</div>
     bla bla
```

The style is changing, I know only the div id.

**UPDATED**

this is my code, same as turbod source and the results are the same too.

so this is the original [html](http://www.sourcepod.com/gcfqwh72-5084)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($buffer);
$id = $doc->getElementById('product_list')
```

And after this code I get the following: [link](http://www.sourcepod.com/fiexgf25-5085)

Comment: Am I correct that the last line in your 'UPDATED' code declaring `$id` should follow with a semicolon for PHP syntax?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the php DomDocument class. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divContent = $xpath->query('//div[@id="product_list"]');
```

Comment: Are any external libraries required to run the code you pasted here? I ask this because the code does not seem to work directly on my server.

Comment: No, but requires the libxml PHP extension. http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.requirements.php  Check your phpinfo(). Have you got any error message?

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm stupid but the line ```$dom->loadHTML($html);``` is causing an error. What should I do?

Comment: This does not retrieve the HTML, it retrieves an object with one property: `length`. The correct answer is the one provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/497139/thw just below. Direct link: not possible on SO for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4):

To save an XML/HTML fragment, you need to save each child node:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = '';
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[@id="product_list"]/node()') as $childNode) {
  $result .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
string(74) "
      <div>
       bla bla bla
      </div>
      bla bla          
"
```

If you only need the text content, you can fetch it directly:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//div[@id="product_list"])')
);
```

Output:

```
string(63) "

       bla bla bla

      bla bla          
"
```

Comment: This is the right answer.

Answer (score -4):

Isn't it enough to do...

```
$id->nodeValue
```