# Capturing a div id value in a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to capture the value of: `<div id="result"></div>` which keep on changing, into a php variable **$foo** and then insert it into the database. **My codes:**

```
<?php 
include('config.inc');
$foo = '<div id="result"></div>';
$query= "INSERT INTO register(name) VALUES('$foo')";
echo $foo;
mysql_query($query) or die('An Error occurred' .mysql_error());
?>
```

*The error:*
Value inserted into the db is:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

, not the value that user has enter... 
Any help please?

Comment: You wanna insert a div in database?

Comment: you're inserting that string into your database so it's very unclear what you expect to happen. Perhaps you want a form field?

Comment: @Cfreak Indeed. What is he expecting to insert?

Comment: "I want to capture the value of: <div id="result"></div>" What value?

Comment: What user value. There is NO code up there to capture anything coming from "outside" the script. And if you're planning on inserting user data like that, better read up about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), because you're HIGHLY likely to be writing code that is utterly vulnerable to it.

Comment: <?php 
include('config.inc');
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divContent = $xpath->query('//div[id="result"]');
echo $divContent;

i've done this but it doesn't display anything and if i comment this line:
$divContent = $xpath->query('//div[id="result"]');

then it display all

Comment: oki i try to explain in simple terms: i want to covert <div id=result></div>, which is constantly changing into php variable $foo. This is so because i want to capture all changing value and insert them in the db

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Use the php DomDocument class. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divContent = $xpath->query('//div[id="product_list"]');
```

Comment: Did you read the question, or am I just not understanding the whole question and answer?

Comment: ^Im confused as well and @Subhash why not just link the url to original question and answer where you got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491598/how-can-i-get-a-div-content-in-php

Comment: The TS wants to have the value between the <div> tags, so indeed, DOMDocument is the answer.

Comment: I believe the OP is missing the fact that PHP lives on the server, and that whatever the user changes has to be passed back, possibly with ajax.

Answer (score 2):

this code will return the content of all divs with id result

```
$value=preg_match_all('/<div id=\"result\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$foo,$estimates);
print_r($estimates);
```

Test this :-

```
 $value=preg_match_all('/<div id=\"result\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$foo,$estimates); $query= "INSERT INTO register(name) VALUES('".$estimates[0]."')";
```

Comment: can you show me step by step please. I've done this but still no luck:

$foo = '<div id="result"></div>';
$value=preg_match_all('/<div id=\"result\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$foo,$estimates);
$query= "INSERT INTO register(name) VALUES('$value')";

Comment: test this : $value=preg_match_all('/<div id=\"result\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$foo,$estimates); $query= "INSERT INTO register(name) VALUES('".$estimates[0]."')";