# get a div from curl website

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

Hello I have this PHP code

```
<?php

/**
* Initialize the cURL session
*/
$ch = curl_init();
/**
* Set the URL of the page or file to download.
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
'https://website/aaa');
/**
* Create a new file
*/
$fp = fopen('index.html', 'w');
/**
* Ask cURL to write the contents to a file
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
/**
* Execute the cURL session
*/
curl_exec ($ch);
/**
* Close cURL session and file
*/
curl_close ($ch);
fclose($fp);


?>
```

I want to get specific divs from this website , (with html dom)

But How?
Keep in mind **Iam very beginner PHP Programmer** Please explain full.

Thanks :X

Comment: I can't get a answer from this topics

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491598/how-can-i-get-a-div-content-in-php