# html form to remote site, fetch the single result and display in my page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the website **mysite.com** and need to fetch the content from another site using a html form and returning the result to my site. The form does not uses method GET but method POST ...

I created a web form to lookup for stolen cars at the website of the chilean police **FROM MY WEBSITE**. Here is the form

```
<form action="http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl/index.php" 
name="form1" id="control" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="accion" value="buscar">
<table id="SEARCH">
<tr><td class="REGISTRATION">
<input name="txtLetras" type="text" class="PLATE" maxlength="2">
</td><td class="SEP">°</td>
<td class="REGISTRATION">
<input name="txtNumeros1" type="text" class="PLATE" maxlength="2">
</td><td class="SEP">°</td>
<td class="REGISTRATION">
<input name="txtNumeros2" type="text" class="PLATE" maxlength="2">
</td></tr></table>
<div id="START" onClick="document.forms['control'].submit();">
CONSULTAR EN EL REGISTRO</div></form>
```

The form must get the result from

```
http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl/index.php
```

where the result is displayed like this (in the police site)

```
<p id="u973-2">
         La patente consultada <span class="Estilo1">NO</span> presenta Encargo..    </p>
```

This result I must get this and display on my page, fetch it.
I know how to fetch static content but how to fetch this kind of result ?
Any idea ?

We have the div ID name at least and is always the same name on this page ...

Trying with AJAX

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> <!-- load jquery via CDN -->
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {//start document ready
      $('#start').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl/index.php',
        data: $("#cdr-form").serialize(),
success: function(d){
   $(".result").html(d);
}
    });
  });
 });//end document ready
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a div content in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491598/how-can-i-get-a-div-content-in-php)

Comment: Are you posting from the same domain `http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl`?

Comment: I am on another site, example.com and need to get the result from http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is not expected to work because of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issues.

#### Use python

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open("http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl/index.php")
br.select_form(name="form1")

br["txtLetras"] = ''
br["txtNumeros1"] = ''
br["txtNumeros2"] = ''

response = br.submit()

# The following gives you full html response
print response.read()

# The following gives you short response info
print response.info()
```

Sample response info when I tested the script with `response.info()`:

```
Date: Fri, 02 Dec 2016 17:04:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.0 (Unix) PHP/5.1.2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.2
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

Good read: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html

My personal favourite is [Scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-to-send-data-via-http-post) which can do a lot of cool things!

#### Using PHP

```
<?php

$url = 'http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl/index.php';

$fields = array(
  'txtLetras' => '',
  'txtNumeros1' => '',
  'txtNumeros2' => '',
);

$fields_string = '';

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
  $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}

rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print $result;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Ref: https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Comment: Any way to do it with PHP ?